# Strict Gitolite configuration

Tags: git, gitolite

I am setting up Gitolite server with strict restrictions. Gitolite doc is good but I think I still need some suggestion if what I am doing is good approach.

- Limit access to master only

Users should have access to only master branch. They cannot cannot create any branch or tag. Also I'll like to prevent force push. Only thing user can do is do simple commit.

I am not if sure this will do

```
repo foo

RW+                     =  @sync
RW   master              =  user
```

- Call service after push

Need to fire trigger or something to notify service of the change and keep db in sync.

- Getting diff

What would be better way to get diff after commit. I need to sync all commits in DB. One way I can think of is clone repo to tmp dir using a user like @sync and run git diff. Is there better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own [update hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook/#hooks), or, in your case, a [post-receive hook](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook/#adding-other-non-update-hooks)

> add this line in the `rc` file, within the `%RC` block, if it's not already present, or uncomment it if it's already present and commented out:

```
LOCAL_CODE => "$ENV{HOME}/local",
```

> put your hooks into that directory, in a sub-sub-directory called "hooks/common":

Such an hook (post-receive) can do a git diff in it: see [this example](https://gist.github.com/cmcculloh/705493#file-post-receive-email-L419)

```
git diff-tree --stat --summary --find-copies-harder $oldrev..$newrev
```

The point is: no need to clone the repo: the hook will be executed after each push.

Comment: Cool. I'll try that. Is my config enough to limit user access to anything but master branch?

Comment: @quazar I believe so, but do use the gitolite access command: it will validate for you those rules: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf-2/#tracing-the-access-control-decision